# Conditional statement between two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. 
One with `events`, columns:

```
id, start_time, end_time, location_id
```

and another with `orders`, columns:

```
id, time_placed, location_id
```

Basically, what I want is a new table with all the events and a new column with the count of orders for that event. The way I would group these orders would be based on whether they were placed in between the start and end time of the event and if they share the same location_id as the event. I'm pretty stumped on how to do this. Each event has it's own unique id and each order has its own unique id.

Due to the size of the tables, I can't really export tables to csv and try anything in Python so it has to be done in mySQL.

I've tried exploring CASE statements and loops but nothing I try works so I'm probably doing it wrong.

So what I want to end up with is a table with variables:
event_id and order_count.

```
id           order_count
1              7383
2              383
3              83838
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are wanting is to look at the `EVENTS` and `ORDERS` tables together, so that constitutes a `JOIN`. BUT, since you are wanting all `events` regardless of if there was an order placed, you want it to be a `LEFT JOIN`. If you did an `INNER JOIN`, you would only end up with events where an order occurred, not all events. So now, your query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM events e
    LEFT JOIN orders o
```

`events` and `orders` are to be joined on `location_id`, so you add that to the `ON` clause of the join:

```
SELECT *
FROM events e
    LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON e.location_id = o.location_id
```

Since the orders are also associated based on the time, you need to add that into the `ON` clause also:

```
SELECT *
FROM events e
    LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON e.location_id = o.location_id
            AND e.start_time <= o.time_placed -- event starts before/at order
            AND e.end_time >= o.time_placed -- event ends after/at order
```

That will correctly join the tables. Next you need to group them. Since you want it by `event`, you will group on the `event` column of `id:

```
SELECT *
FROM events e
    LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON e.location_id = o.location_id
            AND e.start_time <= o.time_placed -- event starts before/at order
            AND e.end_time >= o.time_placed -- event ends after/at order
GROUP BY e.id
```

Lastly, populate the `SELECT` with what fields you want, using `COUNT` to get the count of orders per event:

```
SELECT e.id,
    COUNT(o.id) AS order_count
FROM events e
    LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON e.location_id = o.location_id
            AND e.start_time <= o.time_placed -- event starts before/at order
            AND e.end_time >= o.time_placed -- event ends after/at order
GROUP BY e.id
```

If you want other fields from the `events` table (`start_time`, `end_time`), you will need to add those into the `SELECT` AND `GROUP BY` sections.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a join and count

```
   select  e.start_time, e.end_time, e.location_id,  count(*)
   from events  e  
   inner join  orders o on o.location_id = e.location_id
   group by e.start_time, e.end_time, e.location_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.*, count(o.location_id) as order_count
from events e
left join orders o
  on  o.location_id = e.location_id
  and o.time_placed >= e.start_time
  and o.time_placed <= e.end_time
group by e.id
```

You should have an index on `orders(location_id, time_placed)`. But even with that index, the query might be slow for big tables, because MySQL engine has troubles optimizing JOINs on a range. That issue might be though fixed in recent versions.

Note: I'm assuming that `events.id` is primary key and you use MySQL with default settings. If you get troubles with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, you should add all selected columns from `events` to the GROUP BY clause.